# Create Post tabs in single-{content-type}.php with Custom Field values

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, tabs

My requirement is exactly similar to [Tabbed Post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-tabbed-post).

I have Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin to store data.

So pulling up the requirement from the wordpress support thread:

> Movie Summary | Synopsis | Screens | Trailer | Comments | Add your Review

Movie summary is the_content(), Synopsis is the_excerpt(), Screens and Trailers are custom field values.

I want to know how I can split the content i.e. Summary, Synopsis, Screens, Trailers into Tabs which will reload the page. I do not want to change the tabs using javascript and specifically want to reload page every time.

A working example would be: [Example](http://www.allmovie.com/movie/kung-fu-panda-2-v471909/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [rewrite endpoints](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) to achieve this.

First, register your endpoints:

```
function wpa_movie_endpoints() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'synopsis', EP_PERMALINK );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'screens', EP_PERMALINK );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'trailer', EP_PERMALINK );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_movie_endpoints' );
```

So now in addition to `http://domain.com/post-name/` (or whatever your particular permalink structure is), you'll have:

```
http://domain.com/post-name/synopsis/
http://domain.com/post-name/screens/
http://domain.com/post-name/trailer/
```

You can then check for the existence of these query vars in a template action, or in the template itself, and show the appropriate content:

```
global $wp_query; // may be necessary, depending on where you're using this
if( array_key_exists( 'synopsis', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    echo 'show synopsis!';
}
```

Comment: Wow...never heard of this, very very useful hint for furure projects. I always ended up using nested hierarchical posttypes to achieve that kind of permalink structure.

Comment: Wow. This is exactly what I was looking for. Can you tell me what is the best way to flush rewrite rules. From what I read at [link](http://wpengineer.com/2044/custom-post-type-and-permalink/) rewrite rules need to be flushed for permalinks to work.

Comment: @Praz if this is a plugin, or theme for distribution, the first two examples on [`flush_rewrite_rules`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) are what you should use. if this is a personal theme, you can simply visit the permalinks settings page in admin and rewrites will be flushed.

Comment: @Milo One question though. if I print
`<div><code>
      <?php
      global $wp_rewrite;
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($wp_rewrite->rules);
      echo '</pre>';
      ?>
      </code></div>
`
in my template file I see that these endpoints are added for all post types. How can I restrict it to only single custom post type(movies in this example) and have a different set of endpoints for my second content type? I am using WP Types plugin for managing custom content types.

Comment: @Milo When I try this, the addition of the endpoint to the url causes the 404 template to load. Any suggestions?