# How to divide posts (custom post type) content on multiple pages?

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I have a custom post type called *artist* and each *artist* have some custom fields such as extra text fields and images. I do not want to display all the info about each artist on the same page *single-artist.php*.

So for an example if I want to have one page an artist biography another one artist gallery and another one artist contact. It would also be neccesery to have a navigation to those sub-pages of each artist.

Here is an example of something that I am going after: http://i8.is/artist/birgir-andresson/

I believe there are more than one way to do this so how can something like this be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Post tabs in single-{content-type}.php with Custom Field values](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104955/create-post-tabs-in-single-content-type-php-with-custom-field-values)

Comment: Thanks Milo, this is pretty much what I was looking for.